# Find the value of $\alpha^{\frac13}+\beta^{\frac13}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $f(x)=x^2-5x+8, f(\alpha)=0$ and $f(\beta)=0$ then find the value of $\alpha^{\frac13}+\beta^{\frac13}$

$$\alpha+\beta=5$$
$$\alpha \beta=8$$
$$\alpha^{\frac 1 3}=\frac 2 {\beta^{\frac 1 3}}$$

what should I do next?

Comment: You could just use the Quadratic formula to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ directly (though they are complex numbers...)

Comment: Presumably $\alpha, \beta$ are distinct, else we have more possibilities for the sum.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(\alpha)^{1/3}=c,(\beta)^{1/3}=d$ then $(c+d)^3=c^3+d^3+3cd(c+d)$ thus we have $(c+d)^3=k_1+k_2(c+d)$ where $k_1=\alpha+\beta,k_2=3((\alpha)(\beta))^{1/3}$ let $c+d=y$ then we have $y^3=5+6y$ we can see that $-1$ is one of the solutions for y other two can be found out by polynomial division.

Comment: Your method, while giving a good start, misses two thirds of the possible values of $\alpha^{1/3}+\beta^{1/3}$. A problem is that the formula $(\alpha\beta)^{1/3}=\alpha^{1/3}\beta^{1/3}$ is true only for carefully chosen branches of the complex cube root.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can improve the method?

Comment: What are the alternative values of $z=\alpha^{1/3}\beta^{1/3}$? You are given that $z^3=8$.

Comment: $Z=2,-1\pm i\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(\alpha)=0$ and $f(\beta)=0$, so $\alpha, \beta$ are solutions of the given equation $f(x)=x^2-5x+8=0$.

So we say that $\alpha=\frac{5 + i \sqrt{7}}{2}$, $\beta=\frac{5 - i \sqrt{7}}{2}$.

Also $\alpha + \beta= 5$, $\alpha \beta =8$

Let $\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}=a$ and $\beta^{\frac{1}{3}}=b$

Now $(a+b)^3 =a^3 + b^3+3ab(a+b)\implies (\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}})^3= \alpha + \beta + 3\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}\beta^{\frac{1}{3}}(\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}}) \implies (\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}})^3 =5+6(\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}})\implies m^3-6m-5=0$ (taking $(\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}})=m$)

Now $m^3-6m-5=0 \implies (m+1)(m^2-m-5)=0\implies m=-1, \frac{1\pm \sqrt{21}}{2}$

Hence values of $\alpha^{\frac{1}{3}}+\beta^{\frac{1}{3}}$ are $-1, \frac{1\pm \sqrt{21}}{2}$.

Comment: It depends on the choice of the branch of the cube root whether $\alpha^{1/3}\beta^{1/3}=(\alpha\beta)^{1/3}$ or not. You have a 1-in-3 chance of getting it right, and are missing six out of nine possible values for $\alpha^{1/3}+\beta^{1/3}$. Mind you, the problem setter may also have missed those :-/

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I understand you point. But for a beginner, is it not tough to think like an expert like you ?  I think, in the primary stage  if they have thought in  these way, they will afraid to solve problems in Mathematics. Although for learning and living in Mathematics they must have to think in this way. Am I right or wrong? Thank you for your valuable advice.